# how to disable parent.lock file for firefox when running ruby mine

Tags: ruby, firefox, rubymine

We have recently upgraded our firefox version from 45 to 52.1. After the upgrade we have been facing a issue with parent.lock file created by firefox profile. 
If there is a instance of firefox open then I am not able to run my scripts in ruby mine.
I am trying to do two things:
1. Disable parent.lock file 
2. or adding code to ignore the file in ruby mine. For this I tried to add the below line.
Find.reject { |x| x.match('*\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox/Profiles/x6lel6m4.default') }
but it did not work as reject method is not defined for FIND module. 
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure if this is the solution but, this is what we did to overcome the above problem. Turns out profiles have been deprecated and cannot be used with the new geckodriver. So we updated our geckodriver version from below link [link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.17.0) and added the below code

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
profile = profile
Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)
Watir::Browser.new(browser, marionette: true, desired_capabilities:capabilities, options: options)
```

This code will create a new profile everytime we run the script.
The website we are loading has a certificate, I was not able to add it instead we are ignoring the certificate.